# Удаление элемента из ConcurrentHashMap добавленного первым

Tags: java

В программе используется ConcurrentHashMap для хранения <String, Long>. Его максимальная вместимость  - 10 элементов.

Мне необходимо при добавлении 11 элемента в ConcurrentHashMap удалять тот, который был добавлен самым первым. К примеру:

```java
ConcurrentHashMap<String, Long> result = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
result.put('A' - 1);
result.put('B' - 2);
. . . 
result.put('Z' - 10);
```

Как сделать, чтобы при:

```java
result.put('Е' - 11);
```

Удалялся именно:

```java
result.put('A' - 1);
```

И так далее по списку. Может быть есть встроенные функции или идеи как можно реализовать подобный функционал?

Comment: HashMap не предполагает сохранение порядка элементов...

Comment: Насчёт идей смотрите: [Concurrent LRU cache implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40239485/), если коротко, то можно использовать синхронизированную `LinkedHashMap` или класс [`Cache`](https://guava.dev/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html) из библиотеки Guava.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, во первых структура HashMap здесь не подойдет, нужно то, что сохраняет порядок, например LinkedHashMap, что касается основной идеи, то можно сделать класс обертку для LinkedHashMap, и контролировать количество элементов, вот пример:

```
public class Wrapper<K, V> {

private LinkedHashMap<K, V> linkedHashMap;

private Integer maxSize;

public Wrapper(Integer maxSize) {
    this.maxSize = maxSize;
    linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
}

public void put(K key, V value) {
    if (maxSize == linkedHashMap.size()) {
        linkedHashMap.remove(linkedHashMap.keySet().iterator().next());
    }
    linkedHashMap.put(key, value);
}
```

Comment: у автора `ConcurrentHashMap`, если именно потокобезопасная структура данных была выбрана специально, то вам стоит синхронизировать доступ к хешмапе, как минимум чтобы не более 1 писателя было, так как, емнип, LinkedHashMap не потокобезопасный.

Comment: в методе put стоит сначала проверить, добавляем мы новый ключ или обновляеи существующий

Comment: ну и нет необходимости вручную следить за размером, есть же конструкторы с параметром для максимального количества ключей и методы типа `removeEldestEntry`. Также не совсем уверен, что метод `.keySet()` вернет ключи в нужном порядке.

Comment: @tym32167 я думаю если ему это нужно, он сам и распишет, моя задача подсказать идею

Comment: @tym32167 касательно проверки ключа согласен, можно было и добавить, но остальное на плечах автора

Comment: Ваша имплементация просто может не сработать, потому как вот это `linkedHashMap.keySet()` непонятно в каком порядке вернет элементы.

Comment: Вернёт элементы в порядке выставки

Comment: нет, не вернет. См [доку](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#keySet--) - `he results of the iteration are undefined`

Comment: Друзья, спасибо за варианты ответов, но как было раньше сказано, нужен потокобезопасная структура данных. Такой вариант уже создан, мне нужно видо изменить, потому решил уточнить есть ли обходные пути

Comment: во первых, читайте фразу полностью, `If the map is modified while an iteration over the set is in progress (except through the iterator's own remove operation), the results of the iteration are undefined`, если не доверяете мне - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190083/does-entryset-in-a-linkedhashmap-also-guarantee-order#:~:text=According%20to%20the%20Javadocs%2C%20yes,map%20(insertion%2Dorder).]
и во вторых, по логике, вспомните структуру данных под капотом linkedhashmap, для того чтобы вернуть ключи в произвольном порядке, разработчикам пришлось бы раскидать рандомно значения, зачем?

Comment: К сожалению, данный вариант не подходит, так как у меня ровно такая же реализация, и она удаляет "рандомный" элемент. Думаем с командой над другой структурой хранения

Comment: Пришлось глянуть в потроха метода keySet, там и правда по порядку, my bad. Почему то я думал, что порядок только для entrySet, хз почему ¯\_(ツ)_/¯